# Python simple string cycle

Tags: python, string

What it should look like:

```
enter word: word
enter number: 5

word
word+word
word+word+word
word+word+word+word
word+word+word+word+word
```

What I had:

```
for i in range(1,number+1):
    print(word*i)
```

also I tried it with something like this:

```
for row in range(1,number+1):
    for number in range(1,row+1):
        print(word, end='+')
    print()
```

None of them were working as wanted.

**Thanks for the answer from Cyber, the solution is great and short, but I was trying to do it with for loop and "end" and "sep" (maybe even if loop), is there a way to do it only with those ?**

Comment: Show us what you tried and what you expect.

Comment: I am sorry it wasn't there the first time, I posted it from mobile.

Comment: @Matis, Cyber's solution is the best way to do this. Recursion and a while loop could also be done. Maybe we are not understanding your use of the word `cycle`. But I believe it would be best to accept his answer (both in your code and on stackoverflow).

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding I meant loops.

Comment: @Matis, Cyber is using a loop in his answer, so it should be fine ^^ Also, to notify a user that a comment has been made, use the `@username` feature :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def repeat(word, num):
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        print('+'.join(word for _ in range(i)))
```

Testing

```
>>> repeat('hello',4)
hello
hello+hello
hello+hello+hello
hello+hello+hello+hello
```